Truth of a statement maintained when performing equal operations
If we have two expressions, a+b, and b+a, and we assume that: a+b=b+a
if you subtract b from both sides, giving you: a=a
Knowing that a=a is a true statement, does this prove that a+b=b+a is also true?  Generally speaking, can a true statement only come about from another true statement?  Is it possible for a false statement/equality to produce a true statement? 

You just said you assume $a+b=b+a.$ You can prove $a+b=b+a$ if you assume it. You say that subtracting $b$ from both sides gives you $a=a,$ which seems to skip a lot. You might be able to show $(a+b)-b=a,$ but how do you know that $(b+a)-b=a?$

This looks back-to-front.  Starting with $a=a$ and knowing addition is commutative, you could add $b$ to both sides to demonstrate $a+b=b+a$.  It might be simpler, knowing addition is  commutative, to start with $a+b=a+b$ and thus $a+b=b+a$.  If addition were not commutative, then there would be cases where $a+b\not=a+b$

Given any function $f$, you can conclude $f(a) = f(b)$ from $a = b$. Going the other way requires $f$ to be injective.
